Nominalisierung on Sentences with a Da-Word and Infinitiv

Aufgabe: Nominalisieren Sie alle fett gedruckten Verben/Adjektive
Viele Ingenieure träumen davon, menschenähnliche Roboter zu entwickeln.

My try:

Der Entwicklungstraum von menschenähnlichen Roboter von vielen Ingenieure

I am not sure if this is right, but I have a few questions.

What role does "zu" play in the nominaliserung above?
What do we with "davon" when we do nominalisierung?
My teacher told me, we have to use "durch" for the subject but it sounds weird to me. How can we go through a vielen Ingenieure?


Let me correct your worksheet first:

Viele Ingenieure träumen davon , menschenähnlichen Roboter zu entwickeln.

You should make a noun phrase from those verb phrases. As there are two clauses here. So two verb phrases. Let's start with the initial verb phrase:

der Traum vieler Ingenieure, menschenähnliche Roboter zu entwickeln

This makes the finite verb a noun and the subject a genitive attribute of that noun. That davon is a forward reference to the second clause. You can't replicate this in the noun phrase, but you don't need to either. We don't have a complete sentence as there is no main clause.
Now let's turn the second clause into noun phrase:

Viele Ingenieure träumen von der Entwicklung menschenähnlicher Roboter.

This time the davon becomes replaced with a prepositional object von+dative and the noun phrase has to be put in dative and genitive instead of nominative and genitive. And the result is a complete sentence as we replaced the dependent clause only.
Are we done? Well, we could conflate both options into a single noun phrase:

der Traum vieler Ingenieure von der Entwicklung menschenähnlicher Roboter

This is valid and even common. You can simply concatenate them.

Durch

entwickeln -> Entwicklung
träumen -> Traum

wird beim Platztausch der Satzteile:

Viele Ingenieure träumen davon, menschenähnliche Roboter zu entwickeln.

zu

Die Entwicklung menschenähnlicher Roboter ist der Traum vieler Ingenieure.

aber auch

Der Traum vieler Ingenieure ist die Entwicklung menschenähnlicher Roboter.

ist möglich.
Das "zu" im Ursprungssatz begleitet lediglich den Infinitiv.
In meinen Beispielen kann ich auf das "davon" verzichten. Man träumt von etwas, bzw. dieses Etwas ist ein Traum.
Welcher Satzbau dem Lehrer vorschwebt, der ein "durch" sehen möchte, kann ich nicht erraten.

Die Entwicklung menschenähnlicher Roboter wird durch den Traum vieler Ingenieure befeuert.

könnte ich bilden, aber das verleiht dem Satz einen Inhalt, den er zuvor nicht hatte.
